# In heroku, System.getenv doesn't work in Build.scala of sbt

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am developing web application using Play2 + scala in Heroku. My company has private repository and the repository have our original library. And my application use the library, so I wrote the folloing Build.scala:

```
 resolvers := Seq(
    "maven proxy repo" at System.getenv("SBT_PROXY_REPO") + "/repo"$
 ),
 credentials += Credentials(System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_REALM"), System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_HOST"), System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER"), System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_PASS")) )
```

But System.getenv doesn't work when deploying into heroku. I've already made sure the environment values exist in my application by using `heroku config`. Is it possible to use System.getenv in Build.scala? And I don't want to write directory because the values are concealed information. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because config vars aren't available at build time.  There's [this labs feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) which changes that.  Not sure if it's your problem (don't use Scala), but I'd be curious to know if that does it for you.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I want to know. It works perfectly with using the feature.